# Variable value is null inside TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK state

Tags: android

I want to perform some operation with calling number on call received or TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK state. I am getting null value inside the

```
 if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){}
```

My code is as below-

```
    // onReceive function of the Broadcast Receiver
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

             String incommingCall = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);                  


                Toast.makeText(context,"Call from "+ incommingCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// value of **incomingcall** is present like..+918000000000. etc

                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){

                Toast.makeText(context,"Call from extra_state_offHOOk "+ incommingCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// value of **incomingcall** is null.

                }
            }
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is no String extra matching `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` in the `Intent` for the broadcast you've received.

The best way to protect against the null pointer is to rearrange you `if` statement to:

```
if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
```

Then, you'll handle it only when `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` is present.

Comment: TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK is present in my context but inside if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){} value of incommingCall  is null

Comment: `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is only valid if the new state is not RINGING (see the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)), so `incommingCall` will be null in that case. You need to add an `if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))` check before you try to do anything with `incommingCall`.